# php command line is not responding after install

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I successfully compiled PHP 5.4.30 from source on centos5.5.  But commands like `./php -v` `./php -m` will not return any output. Neither will `./php -f file.php` command.  In fact, only `./php --help` generates output.

I have installed php.5.5.20 and php.5.4.36 with the same poor results.

php.5.3.x works and will generate output.

All the installations use the following ./configure options:

```
sudo   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/newco \
            --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl \
            --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl \
            --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local \
            --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/newco \
            --with-curl=/usr/lib \
            --with-apxs2=/usr/local/newco/httpd/bin/apxs \
            --with-mysql \
            --with-mysqli=mysqlnd \
            --enable-embedded-mysqli \
            --enable-sigchild \
            --enable-mbstring=yes \
            --enable-debug=no \
            --enable-soap  \
            --with-pdo-mysql
```

PHP is running OK for all Apache requests.

```
$ ./php-config

Options:
  --prefix            [/usr/local/newco]
  --includes          [-I/usr/local/newco/include/php -I/usr/local/newco/include/php/main -I/usr/local/newco/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/newco/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/newco/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/newco/include/php/ext/date/lib]
  --ldflags           [ -L/usr/local/newco/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -L/usr/kerberos/lib]
  --libs              [-lcrypt   -lcrypt -lreadline -lncurses -lrt -lcurl -lz -lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lm -ldl -lnsl  -lxml2 -lz -lm -lcurl -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lcrypt -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lxml2 -lz -lm -lcrypt ]
  --extension-dir     [/usr/local/newco/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525]
  --include-dir       [/usr/local/newco/include/php]
  --man-dir           [/usr/local/newco/php/man]
  --php-binary        [/usr/local/newco/bin/php]
  --php-sapis         [ apache2handler cli cgi]
  --configure-options [--prefix=/usr/local/newco --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/newco --with-curl=/usr/lib --with-apxs2=/usr/local/newco/httpd/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --enable-embedded-mysqli --enable-sigchild --enable-mbstring=yes --enable-debug=no --enable-soap --with-pdo-mysql ]
  --version           [5.4.30]
  --vernum            [50430]
```

Comment: perhaps a permission issue, what permissions do you have on the file?

Comment: is the path to php in your working directory as `./php` implies, if not try just `php`

Comment: permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24695117 Jan 19 15:16 php`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I'm too new to comment so I have to send this as an answer instead.

I don't see the --enable-cli directive in your installation config file. Including that directive and then recompiling *should* fix the issue.

More information on that can be found toward the bottom of the third code snippet box in the following link for your convenience. http://gediminasm.org/post/compile-php

Comment: I recompiled with `-enable-cli` but I get the same results

Comment: `./php-config    --configure-options
--prefix=/usr/local/newco --with-openssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/ssl --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local --with-libxml-dir=/usr/local/newco --with-curl=/usr/lib --with-apxs2=/usr/local/newco/httpd/bin/apxs --with-mysql --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --enable-embedded-mysqli --enable-sigchild --enable-mbstring=yes --enable-debug=no --enable-soap --with-pdo-mysql --enable-cli
`

Comment: at command line I would type 
`which php` 
and see if that gives you any results. Ultimately, you have been issuing commands with `./php` which tells your terminal to look in the current directory for php... all of your commands should exclude the `./` and just go with `php -v`

Comment: I'm using `./php` since I'm in the /usr/local/newco/bin folder that has the newly installed binary.  I'm trying to validate the install before proceeding.  `which php` finds no php .